# Predict Function & Generating a Training Set

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to use the Predict[] function to do a regression analysis.  I have the data imported from a CSV and based on my past Python experience the libraries I used always have a slick way to take a percentage of the data and use it as a training set.

Does Mathematica have any function to take a portion of a dataset and use it for training?  Most of the examples I can find are using ExampleData where this step is already done.

Thank You

Comment: Check my resource function [CrossValidateModel](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CrossValidateModel/).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Did not know about that WFR function -- thanks for sharing!

Comment: I tend to use the TrainTestSplit resource function:  https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TrainTestSplit (but @SjoerdSmit 's CrossValidateModel is also very nice)

Comment: Another note I'd like to make is that Predict and Classify already do training-test validation internally. Most of the time you don't need to do this manually.

Comment: There is a checkmark next to (each) answer. You can click on it to accept that answer. You can also upvote answers.

Comment: I'd also like to note that `Predict` and `Classify` already do training/validation splits as part of the internal model selection process, so there's not need to go overboard too much with doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To take only some piece of a dataset works the same like for matrices or arrays. E.g.:

```
d = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}];
```

[image]

To get the first 3 rows:

```
d[[;;3]]
```

[image]

To get the last 3 rows:

d[[-3 ;; -1]]

[image]

To get the first 30%:

d[[;; Round[Length[d] 0.3]]]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  CrossValidateModel, TrainTestSplit, and direct parsing of the Dataset are all good options and answer what I was looking for.  Thank you all.